# PHP Reforce Search Engine

Tags: php, mysql, forms, if-statement

I have this Search option, where it looks for the Title and the Category Referent to the variable requested by the FORM.

```
//This could be Reference or Product Name
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, sanitize($_GET['search']));

//this could be a specific category or Empty(used to reference number)
$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, sanitize($_GET['category']));
$x = 0; 
$q = str_replace(array("\\",";"), "", $name);  // remove ALL backslashes & remove ALL ";" -> for sql security: no (simple) injection of commands
$q = trim($q);
$search_exploded = explode(" ", $q);

foreach($search_exploded as $search_each ) { 

$x++; 

   if($x == 1) { 
         $wherearr[]= "ads_title LIKE '%$search_each%' AND category_id = '$category' AND ads_active = 1 AND ads_end = 0"; 
   } else {     
         $wherearr[]= "ads_title LIKE '%$search_each%' AND category_id = '$category' AND ads_active = 1 AND ads_end = 0"; 
   }

}

//$wherearr[] is used to create a new variable $construct to insert to SQL like "Select * from Where $construct"
```

I want to able people to search also by product reference.

The goal is, when the person inserts the reference, it will automatically go to the product.

Add this field:

```
 $wherearr[]= "ads_reference LIKE '%$search_each%' AND ads_active = 1 AND ads_end = 0";
```

How can I do it using the form that I created before?

Comment: What is the different between the `if` and the `else` in your example? and why not just use simple `if` in order to check if search is reference and set the SQL query accordingly?

Comment: the differente is... If the user searches for a title... the script will search in the first way.. if dont find... try again.. SOmething like that xD

Comment: Can u help to put it better and give the chance to search by Reference too

Comment: Can you please provide example to `$search_exploded`? is it list of titles? how can you distinguish between title and reference?

Comment: of course. 1 sec , I'll add there, the Reference option by Form is the same as Category Variable. so, only will change the DB columns.

Comment: What do u recommend to do?... Plz this is for a Schooll Project...

Comment: I am sorry but it is still no understood-able. Assume you have names of `foo,bar` and reference of `abc`. How did your `q` will look like? is it like: `foo bar abc`?  or `foo abc`? or just `abc` how can you tell the different between names and reference? 
Also regarding `$wherearr`, where do you init it and where do you use it?

Comment: The titles are distinguished by Names and the category are distinguished by ID from DB.

Comment: I asked about the **reference** - how can I get them?

Comment: The reference is called by the $name, its when the user writes in the form. then he select in the form all the categories or an empty value called "Reference". If he sellect that value, and writes something like "FC888" will show a product

Comment: My goal is to give all options.. By reference, or By Categories

Comment: the $wherearr[] is a variable to use as #construct to SELECT ** FROM WHERE $construct.... dont worry about that, i just want to add Reference to the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand you question but I will try.

First try to extract all the data you want from the `GET` request.

Some assumption:

1. You used `AND category_id = '$category'` so I assume `$_GET['category']` retrieve category_id.
2. When extracting `$_GET['search']` you gets list of names separate by white space. So if you have names like `foo` and `bar` the `$_GET['search']` will be "foo bar"
3. If the `category_id` is empty I assume that `$name` contains Reference

Now try this code:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, sanitize($_GET['search']));
$category_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, sanitize($_GET['category']));
$q = str_replace(array("\\",";"), "", $name); 

$search_exploded = explode(" ", trim($q));
$wherearr = array();
$querySufix = " AND ads_active = 1 AND ads_end = 0";

foreach($search_exploded as $search_each) {
    if ($category_id)
        $wherearr[]= "ads_title LIKE '%$search_each%' AND category_id = '$category_id '" . $querySufix;
    else 
        $wherearr[]= "ads_reference LIKE '%$search_each%'". $querySufix;
}
```

Comment: ok, ty, you give me a good ideia... i did it different like 
        `$x++; 

        if(empty($category)) {
            $wherearr[]= "ads_reference LIKE '%$search_each%'". $querySufix;
        } elseif($x == 1) { 
            $wherearr[]= "ads_title LIKE '%$search_each%' AND category_id = '$category'". $querySufix; 
        } else {     
            $wherearr[]= "ads_title LIKE '%$search_each%' AND category_id = '$category'". $querySufix; 
        }`